# Implementing a queue in Python - two isempty() methods giving different answers

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, queue

I'm doing some basic Python programming practice exercises and tried to implement a queue (using lists). Unfortunately, I'm getting behavior for my isempty() function that I don't understand. When running the code below, the last two lines give different answers: A yields False, while B yields True. Why doesn't A also yield False?

```
class Queue:

  def __init__(self):
    self.items = []

  def push(self,item):
    self.items.insert(0,item)

  def pop(self):
    return self.items.pop()

  def size(self):
    return len(self.items)

  def isempty(self):
    return self.size == 0

q = Queue()
q.push("a")
q.push("b")
print(q.pop())
print(q.isempty())
print(q.pop())
print(q.isempty()) # shouldn't this (A)...
print(q.size()==0) # ...and this (B) yield the same answer?
```

Comment: `self.size` is a method. `self.size()` returns size, but `self.size` is the method itself, not a number.

Comment: While your class does behave like a queue, `push` and `pop` are terms usually associated with stacks (which are LIFO data structures). Consider using the terms `enqueue` and `dequeue` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your `isempty()` method to:

```
def isempty(self):
    return self.size() == 0
```

Comment: My pleasure! If an answer here solves your problem, please mark it as accepted if you don't mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of `Queue.isempty()` is checking to see if the method `size` is equal to the integer `0`, which will never be true.

```
class Queue:                 

  def __init__(self):        
    self.items = []          

  def push(self,item):       
    self.items.insert(0,item)

  def pop(self):             
    return self.items.pop()  

  def size(self):            
    return len(self.items)   

  def isempty(self):         
    return self.size == 0    

q = Queue()                  
print(q.size)
```

Produces:

> <bound method Queue.size of <__main__.Queue object at 0x02F4EA10>>

The easiest solution is to use Christopher Shroba's suggestion to modify your `Queue.isempty()` implementation to use the list's size method.